# ClassNotFoundException when using java servlet to save files

Tags: apache, servlets

I use MyExclipse + JAVA  to develop web project. I upload a file using ajaxFileUpload and attempt to save the file in Java Servlet. I use apache tomcat as the server to run my project.
But when I run the project, an exception as follows occurs. I google it, it says the reason may be not importing relevant jars in Java Builder Path. But I have configured it. So, I am confused why.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwf4x.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA3Cg.png)

Comment: Add you errors in code snippet in qustion only,not as image!

Comment: The exception is thrown at runtime so build path is not an issue,make sure the jar is available to the project at runtime.Is this jar placed with the project library?